# Date Range in an Access Crosstab

Tags: sql, ms-access

Trying to get a Crosstab to bring up a prompt when a query is opened to allow a date range (start and end) to be input (dd-mm-yyyy) so that only this data comes back when the query is ran.

Currently sitting on the following code;

```
TRANSFORM Count(AlphaData.[Invoice]) AS CountOfInvoice
SELECT AlphaData.[Reason], Count(AlphaData.[Invoice]) AS [Total Of Invoice]
FROM AlphaData
WHERE ((AlphaData.[DateRaised]) Between AlphaData.[DateRaised] And AlphaData.[DateRaised])
GROUP BY AlphaData.[Reason]
PIVOT Format([DateRaised],"Short Date");
```

But cannot for the life of me get around the "MS Access DB engine does not recognise 'Alphadata.[DateRaised:]' as a valid field name or expression" issue.

The "WHERE" portion of the query does work in other queries, but it just goes to pot when it's applied in a crosstab.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems a bit mixed up. How about:

```
PARAMETERS
    [From Date:] DateTime,
    [To Date:] DateTime;
TRANSFORM 
    Count(*) AS CountOfInvoice
SELECT 
    AlphaData.[Reason], 
    Sum(AlphaData.[Invoice]) AS [Total Of Invoice]
FROM 
    AlphaData
WHERE 
    AlphaData.[DateRaised] Between [From Date:] And [To Date:]
GROUP BY 
    AlphaData.[Reason]
PIVOT 
    Format([DateRaised],"Short Date");
```

Comment: as ever my man you're a living legend. This worked perfectly. Also, learnt something, huzzah!

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the parameters to the query:

```
PARAMETERS [Start Date] DateTime, [End Date] DateTime;
TRANSFORM Count(AlphaData.Invoice) AS CountOfInvoice
SELECT AlphaData.Reason, Count(AlphaData.Invoice) AS [Total Of Invoice]
FROM AlphaData
WHERE (((AlphaData.DateRaised) Between [Start Date] And [End Date]))
GROUP BY AlphaData.Reason
PIVOT Format([DateRaised],"Short Date");
```

(**note:** parameter added as the first line, and then used in the `Between` statement).

If you're using the graphical interface you need to look for the Parameter option:
[image]

and enter your parameters in the dialog box:
[image]

I didn't realise this would happen with a cross-tab as you can just type the parameter in for a select query:

```
SELECT Invoice, Reason, DateRaised
FROM AlphaData
WHERE DateRaised=[Start Date]
```